# How to create a trigger mysql on new row?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have a big table with accountID, deviceID, timestamp as primary keys and a lot of fields with different data types.
The table is very active, a new 50 to 80 rows are added every second by a JAVA server that receives data from internet.

Now I need to clone some new rows when a new row with an specific accountID and deviceID are inserted and change the accountID field, on the clone, by a new one.

I'm new with MySQL triggers. Can a trigger shot itself?
I don't need that the trigger shot itself but since the cloned row will be added to the same table maybe it can happen, thought.

Comment: Check `MySQL trigger after insert` or `MySQL trigger after update` : after an insert / update in your bdd you can execute some code (check the NEW.accountID and OLD.accountID for example and insert or update a row according to what you get !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that inside a trigger, because a trigger cannot run queries on the table on which it was fired.

One solution would be to create a stored procedure, that you application would invoke when it needs to insert data. The procedure would then insert the two records.

So something like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_insert_proc(
    IN p_accountID INT, 
    IN p_deviceID INT, 
    IN p_timestamp DATETIME,
    IN p_col1 VARCHAR(20),
    IN p_col2 VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE p_accountID_new INT;

    -- "regular" insert
    INSERT INTO mytable(accountID, deviceID, timestamp, col1, col2) 
        VALUES(p_accountID, p_deviceID, p_timestamp, p_col1, p_col2);

    SET p_accountID_new = ... -- whatever you need
    -- "clone" insert
    INSERT INTO mytable(accountID, deviceID, timestamp, col1, col2) 
        VALUES(p_accountID_new, p_deviceID, p_timestamp, p_col1, p_col2);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This assumes that there are two additional columns in the table after the primary key columns. You can adapt this according to your table structure.

Comment: I already have a method to insert data with my application and also clones, but I'm must to add new code to create an extra clone only for an specific account on specific conditions and my boss doesn't want to because he says that it will slow down the application performance and there's a chance to get a new bug, only just for one account(very risky). So, that's why I was thinking in to do it something with an SQL trigger. Anyway, your info is useful, now I know what can and cannot do with an SQL trigger.